# Printing difference of adjacent numbers without using array

Tags: c, gcc

I recently found a C puzzle to write a program to read a set of integers x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ……. till a `-1` is entered as input..

After reading the `-1`, the program should print the difference between each adjacent numbers. 
Ie,  x<sub>1</sub>-x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>-x<sub>2</sub>,…..

eg:
Input:
`1 2 4 7 11 -1`

Output
`1 2 3 4`

The output is the result of (2-1), (4-2), (7-4), (11-7)

The problem is that the program **shouldn’t be using an array.** Even the dynamically allocated arrays won’t do.

I tried a lot and this is my what I’ve come with

```
#include<stdio.h>

int a, b;
int fn()
{
    int r=b-a;
    a=b;
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if(b!=-1)
    {
        printf("%d ", fn());
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d ", fn() );
    return 0;
}
```

The above program uses a recursive function but in this method, since it is like a stack, the value that was calculated last is being printed first instead of the value that was calculated first being printed first.

ie, output for the same input as above is:
`4 3 2 1`
instead of 
`1 2 3 4`

Is there a way to save the values taken from this call stack (please correct me if I’m not using the right terms) and push them again to stack so that while retrieving the first calculated value will now be the first to be popped?

Eg:
I got the values 4, 3, 2 & 1 with `fn()` because it was like this on stack before `4` was popped:

```
4
3
2
1
```

Suppose I pop all elements from the stack and push them to another stack in the order in which they were popped. Then the new stack would be

```
1
2
3
4
```

(ie, `4` got popped and pushed first (& hence ended up in bottom), then `3` got popped & pushed and so on.)

If this could be done, we could just pop elements from the new stack and display them in the order in which they are popped.

Note: The stack that I'm referring to is the call stack & not an explicitly created stack (which would probably need array).

Or maybe there’s a simpler way?

EDIT: I need the inputting and outputting phases to be separate and not interleaved. No output should be displayed before the end of input is signaled with the `-1`.

EDIT: The program can't use files to store the input to be read back later.

Comment: Don't you just need to print the result before going recursive?

Comment: @John3136 I just want to print but in the correct order.

Comment: @John3136 I also want the inputting phase and outputting phase to be seperate and not interleaved.

Comment: you can write the return results to a file and when you encounter -1 on the I/P you can read back the results from the file and direct it to stdout. But you'll have to read your file in reverse order and will need to mess up with `fseek()` & similar functions.

Comment: @ManjinderSinghHanjra It can't use files. Sorry I didn't mention that before. Edited.

Comment: Is there any particular pattern in the input, like AP, GP, something like that or any random number can be on the input? In the former case, it'll be easy to find the solution.

Comment: The solution is to use recursion and continue recursing until the `-1` end condition is found.  Then print the diffs, starting from the first (this may involve a 2nd recursion).

Comment: Or if you can't use recursion, then use a `'queue'` (FIFO) instead of a `'stack'` (LIFO) so that differences are popped in order.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin But that would still mean using an array, right? I can't use arrays.

Comment: @J...S A _queue_ can be done with an _array_, yet other non-array means can be used to form a _queue_.

Comment: @chux How can I do this problem with a second recursion?

Comment: @ManjinderSinghHanjra No the input has no pattern. It can be any integer.

Comment: @chux Is there a way to implement a queue without array other than using the method you gave? Sorry to keep asking you questions but a google search didn't yield other results.

Comment: @J...S Certainly there are many ways to implement a queue other than with arrays and as [this answer's two ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45575186/2410359).

Comment: If you are allowed to use data-structures other than arrays, then the answer by @chux is an exact solution for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to save the values taken from this call stack ... and push them again to stack so that while retrieving the first calculated value will now be the first to be popped?

Recurse each time a number is read (except -1).

Create a linked list made up of variables in previous recursion.

No arrays used except for `printf()` format.

A little more work needed to avoid a space after the last printed `int`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct list {
  const struct list *prev;
  int i;
} list;

void print_list(const list *previous) {
  if (previous && previous->prev) {
    print_list(previous->prev);
    printf("%d ", previous->i - previous->prev->i);
  }
}

void JSfoo(const list *previous) {
  list node = { previous, 0 };
  int cnt = scanf("%d", &node.i);
  if (cnt == 1 && node.i != -1) {
    JSfoo(&node);
  } else {
    print_list(previous);
    puts("");
  }
}

int main(void) {
  JSfoo(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Output (not interleaved)

```
1 2 4 7 11 -1
1 2 3 4
```

---

An alternative would maintain a queue to negate the need to recursively print.  Same output.

The below uses a circular queue.  Notice only 1 `next` pointer needed.  The queue handle needs to only point to the end of the queue.  No need for pointers to the head and tail.  Insertion is `O(1)`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct que {
  struct que *next;
  int i;
} que;

// Pass in the tail of the queue and return the updated tail
// `tail` points to the head.  (Circular queue)
que *que_append(que *tail, que *node) {
  if (tail) {
    node->next = tail->next;
    tail->next = node;
  } else {
    node->next = node;
  }
  return node;
}

void JSfoo(que *tail) {
  que node;
  int cnt = scanf("%d", &node.i);
  if (cnt == 1 && node.i != -1) {
    tail = que_append(tail, &node);
    JSfoo(tail);
  } else if (tail) {
    que *head = tail->next;
    while (head != tail) {
      printf("%d ", head->next->i - head->i);
      head = head->next;
    }
    puts("");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess my folly lay in thinking that a stack (or a queue) can be implemented only with arrays. But is there a way through which a recursive function's return values can be reversed by using another recursive function or anything?

Comment: @J...S Function calls are typical implemented with a _stack_: last in, first out.  Yet code's goal is a queue.  first in - first out.  (The difference  bit is just a smoke-screen for the fundamental issue.)  I do not see a way to only use local values and returns to implement your goal, hence the queue.  Let me know if you find something.

Comment: @J...S Using `malloc()`, even recursion is not needed.  Just form a queue using dynamically allocated data.

Answer (score 2):

Do you expect the program to stop taking any more input chars from user immediately after entering "-1" and followed by print of diff seq out?

If not, that is if you allow user to input more chars after "-1", to be ignored by your program till a newline is entered, and at that point, your program can print the diff sequence out. Then you can use the following snippet:

```
unsigned int x, y;
while( scanf("%d",&x)==1 && x != -1 && scanf("%d",&y)==1 && y != -1 )
    printf("%d ",y-x);
printf("\n");
```

EDIT:
thanks @JoëlHecht for pointing out error in the above code, i misread the desired output spec, the following code should fix it:

```
int x, y = -1;
while( scanf("%d",&x)==1 && x != -1 ) {
    if( y != -1 ) printf("%d ",x-y);
    y = x;
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: We can avoid one scanf function by using **while( scanf("%d %d",&x, &y) == 2 && x != -1 && y != -1 )**. scanf function returns number of inputs read successfully.

Comment: With the example it prints 1 3 instead of 1 2 3 4

Comment: thanks @JoëlHecht for point it out, the following code should fix it:
    unsigned int x, y = -1;
    while( scanf("%d",&x)==1 && x != -1 ) {
        if( y != -1 ) printf("%d ",x-y);
        y = x;
    }
    printf("\n");

Comment: @VikasYadav These programs would display the input and output in an interleaved manner. I need the output to be printed only after the input is over.

Comment: They do not interleave input and output on my machine Win 7 and compiler gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1). Did you try this program?

Comment: @VikasYadav I did. Still, it is clear from the code that the output will begin printing before the final `-1` is given.

Comment: @VikasYadav The approach relies on `stdout` buffering the _line_ of output. `stdout` will eventually print, even without a `'\n`, one the buffer reaches some threshold.  Change to `printf("%d\n",y-x);` (add \n) to see the difference.

Comment: @chux i agree on stdout behavior and your suggestion will cause output to be printed one number per line. However, I am not sure what is your point in context of OP question. Let me know if i missed something.

Comment: @J..S When you ran the program, did you see the input output interleaved? I doubt as the STDIN is a line buffered input and it would not pass data to your program (and to scanf) until you hit enter. I assume you would hit enter after entering -1. Maybe that assumption is not correct,  but i tried to state it clearly in my original response.

Comment: If the number of input `int`  was sufficient, `printf()` output could interleave with input - even with line buffered `stdout`.  The `printf()` character count threshold is certainly at least 4K.  So starting about 4k of buffered output, `stdout` may appear, even without `'\n'`.  On other systems that do not line buffer `stdout`, (C does not specified `stdout` is line buffered) , the interleave will be promptly apparent.  All real systems have various limitations.

Comment: Thanks @chux for clarification

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem calling for a *recursive function*. A recursive function (1) takes a value and provides a test for an *exit condition* to break recursion; (2) preforms some operation on data; then (3) calls itself again (*makes a recursive call*) causing the process to repeat.

In your case the value the recursive function needs is (1) the *previously read integer* and then it will read a `current` value from `stdin` (validating and **handling any error**) and *test whether `current` is* `-1` for the *exit condition*. The function must then (2) print the difference between `current` and `previous`. It then need to (3) pass the `current` value as an argument to the recursive function, calling itself again until the exit condition is satisfied.

Putting those pieces together, you can do something similar to the following `difference()` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* for EXIT_FAILURE */

/* recursive function taking previous read value as input */
void difference (int prev)
{
    int current;                /* variable to hold current value */

    if (scanf ("%d", &current) != 1) {  /* read / validate input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (current == -1)               /* recusion exit condition */
        return;

    printf (" %d", current - prev);         /* print difference */

    difference (current);     /* recursive call passing current */
}

int main (void) {

    int n;                          /* variable for first value */

    if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1) {    /* read / validate input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (n == -1)                    /* verify not -1 */
        return 0;

    difference (n);     /* recursive call passing first value */

    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/diffints
1 2 4 7 11 -1
 1 2 3 4
```

**Using a Helper Function to Start Recursion**

If you wanted to tidy things up in `main()` a bit more, you could create a *helper function* that would read the first value and start the recursion. That would leave you nothing but a single call to the helper function in `main()`. This doesn't change the operation of the program at all. Instead of calling and validation the return of `scanf` and making the first call to `difference` in `main()`, those tasks are simply moved to a new function called `diffcheck()` which then calls `difference()` to start the recursion. Completely up to you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* for EXIT_FAILURE */

/* recursive function taking previous read value as input */
void difference (int prev)
{
    int current;                /* variable to hold current value */

    if (scanf ("%d", &current) != 1) {  /* read / validate input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (current == -1)               /* recusion exit condition */
        return;

    printf (" %d", current - prev);         /* print difference */

    difference (current);     /* recursive call passing current */
}

/* helper function to read 1st value and call difference */
void diffcheck (void)
{
    int n;                          /* variable for first value */

    if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1) {    /* read / validate input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (n == -1)                    /* verify not -1 */
        return;

    difference (n);     /* recursive call passing first value */

    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up */
}

int main (void) {

    diffcheck();
    return 0;
}
```

**note:** how `main()` is reduced to a single call to `diffcheck()` which is a lot cleaner than repeating the read/validation and first check everywhere you want to call the `difference` function throughout your code.

Look things over, thinking through the recursive function operation for `difference()`, and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: @DavidCRankin But these programs will begin to print the output before input is over. I need the input and output to be on the screen in a non-interleaved fashion

Answer (score 0):

The program will be

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned int x, y;

   if(!(scanf("%d",&x)==1 && x != -1))
      return 0;

   while(scanf("%d",&y)==1 && y != -1 )
   {
        printf("%d ",y-x);
        x = y;
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You are printing the difference on the go whereas he wants to entirely consume the input first and then print the differences. but your code consumes a number, prints the difference, takes another number and repeats the process until -1 is encountered.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a, b;
void fn()
{
    int r=b-a;
    a=b;

    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("%d ", r);

    if(b!=-1)
        fn();
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    fn();
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The output and input shouldn't be interleaved. Sorry for not saying it before. Edited.